# Combined search query for a few xml documents

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have in each books directory `/books/{book_id}/` a couple of xml documents.
`/books/{book_id}/basic.xml` and `/books/{book_id}/formats.xml`.
First one is

```
    <document book_id="{book_id}">
      <title>The book</title>
    </document>
```

and the second is

```
    <document book_id="{book_id}">
      <format>a</format>
      <format>b</format>
      <format>c</format>
    </document>
```

How can I find all books in `/books/` directory with `format eq 'a'` and `title eq *'book'*` by one query? I have done one variant when I first finding all books by format by `cts:search()` and then filter the result in "for loop" by checking title in basic.xml file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is listed as MarkLogic as well as xQuery.  For completeness, I have included a MarkLogic solution that is a single statement:

```
let $res := cts:search(doc(), cts:and-query(
       (
         cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("title"), '*book*', ('wildcarded'))
         ,
         cts:element-attribute-range-query(xs:QName("document"), xs:QName("book_id"), '=', cts:element-attribute-values(xs:QName("document"), xs:QName("book_id"), (), (), cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("format"), 'b')))
          )
         ) 
)
```

OK. Now lets break this down and have a look.

**Note:** This sample requires a single **range index** on the attribute book_id.

I tool advantage of the fact that you have the same attribute in the same namespace in both types of documents. This allowed the following:

- I could use a single index

  - Then I used element-attribute-values for the list of book_ids
    -- This was constrained by the 'format' element
  - The list of book_ids above was used to filter the books  (range query)
  - Which was then further filtered by the title
  - This approach joins the two documents using a range index which is super-fast - especially on the integer value of the book_id

It should be noted that in this articular case, I was able to isolate the proper documents because title elements only exist in one type of document.

Now, lets look at a cleaner example of the same query.

```
(: I used a word-query so that I could do wildcarded searches for document with 'book' in the title.  This is because your sample has a title 'The Book', yet you search for 'book' so I can olnly conclude that you meant to have wildcard searches :)
let $title-constraint := "*book*"
(: This could also be a sequence :)
let $format-constraint := "a"
(: used for the right-side of the element-range-query :)
let $format-filter := cts:element-attribute-values(xs:QName("document"), xs:QName("book_id"), (), (), cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("format"), $format-constraint))
(: final results :)
let $res := cts:search(doc(), cts:and-query((
                                            cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("title"), $title-constraint, ('wildcarded'))
                                            ,
                                            cts:element-attribute-range-query(xs:QName("document"), xs:QName("book_id"), '=', $format-filter)
                                            )
                             ) )
return $res
```

Comment: Thank you. I missed your answer yesterday and posted today something like yours.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe stating the obvious, the best approach would be to change the model so the format is in the same document as the title and can be matched by a single query.

If that's not possible, one alternative would be to turn on the uri lexicon in the database configuration (if it's not enabled already).

Assuming that the title is more selective than the format, something along the following lines might work.

```
let $title-uris := cts:uris((), (), cts:and-query((
    cts:directory-query("/books/", "infinity"),
    cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("title"), "book")
    )))
let $title-dirs := 
    for $uri in $title-uris
    return fn:replace($uri, "/basic\.xml$", "/")
let $format-uris := cts:uris((), (), cts:and-query((
    cts:directory-query($title-dirs),
    cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("format"), "a")
    )))
let $book-docs := 
    for $uri in $format-uris
    return fn:replace($uri, "/format\.xml$", "/basic.xml")
for $doc in fn:doc($book-docs)
return ... do something with the basic document ...
```

The extra cost beyond the document reads consists of two lookups in the uri lexicon and the string manipulation. The benefit is in reading only the documents that match.

In general, it's better at scale to use the indexes to match the relevant documents instead of reading the documents into memory and filtering out the irrelevant documents. The cts:uris() and cts:search() functions always match using the indexes first (and only filter when the search option is specified). XPaths optimize by matching with the indexes when possible but have to fallback to filtering for some predicates. Unless you're careful, it's usually better to limit XPaths to navigation of nodes in memory.

Hoping that helps,

Answer (score 0):

> How can I find all books in /books/ directory with format eq 'a' and title eq *'book'* by one query?

Try:

```
doc('basic.xml')/document[@book_id='X']/title[contains(., 'book')]]
[doc('format.xml')/document[@book_id='X'][format = 'a']
```

The last predicate, if it turns empty, will result in the `title` to not be found. If it exists, then `title` will be returned.

You should, of course, replace `X` with your ID. And you can set the relative path to include the ID. If you have a set of ID's you want to go over, you can do this:

```
for $id in ('{book_id1}', '{book_id2}')
return 
    doc(concat($id, '/basic.xml'))/document[@book_id=$id]/title[contains(., 'book')]]
    [doc(concat($id, '/format.xml'))/document[@book_id=$id][format = 'a']
```

You'll get the drift ;)

PS: I'm not sure if `{...}` is a legal URI pathpart, but I assume you'll replace it with something sensible. Otherwise, escape it with the appropriate percent-encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found better solution

```
let $book_ids := cts:values(
  cts:element-attribute-reference(xs:QName("document"), xs:QName("book_id") ), 
  (), 
  ("map"), 
  cts:and-query((
    cts:directory-query(("/books/"), "infinity"),
    cts:element-query(xs:QName("title"),"book")
  ))
)
return 
  cts:search(
    /, 
    cts:and-query((
      cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("document"), xs:QName("book_id"), map:keys($book_ids)),
      cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("format"), "a"),
    ))
  )
```